# Как в Libreoffice на линукс сделать конец строки в CSV файле \r\n или \n?

Tags: linux, csv, open-office, libre-office

Как в Libreoffice на линукс сделать конец строки в CSV файле \r\n или \n?

В "правке параметров фильтра" нет такого пункта.

Неужели придется прогонять через unix2dos вручную?

Comment: А на что это влияет?

Comment: homecreditbank не принимает таблички с линуксового офиса. на винде пересохраняем и все ок